# Why does char array display contents on console while string and int arrays dont in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char, int

When i run Console.WriteLine() on an int or string array, it prints (System.String[]), (System.Int32[]). 
but i when do that with a char array, it displays the contents as if they were a string. what is with this weird behavior? 
(ihgfedcba) is what it displays. Can anybody explain why this happens?

```
public static void Test(){
        string[] words_array = new string[9];
        words_array[0] = "football";
        words_array[1] = "handball";
        words_array[2] = "Harry Potter";
        words_array[3] = "Prometheus";
        words_array[4] = "strengh";
        words_array[5] = "Muscles";
        words_array[6] = "weakness";
        words_array[7] = "beauty";
        words_array[8] = "Ali";
        System.Console.WriteLine(words_array);

        int[] int_array = new int[9];
        int_array[0] = 0;
        int_array[1] = 1;
        int_array[2] = 2;
        int_array[3] = 3;
        int_array[4] = 4;
        int_array[5] = 5;
        int_array[6] = 6;
        int_array[7] = 7;
        int_array[8] = 8;
        System.Console.WriteLine(int_array);

        char[] char_array = new char[9];
        char_array[0] = 'i';
        char_array[1] = 'h';
        char_array[2] = 'g';
        char_array[3] = 'f';
        char_array[4] = 'e';
        char_array[5] = 'd';
        char_array[6] = 'c';
        char_array[7] = 'b';
        char_array[8] = 'a';
        System.Console.WriteLine(char_array);           
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` has [a specific overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Char___) which takes a `char[]`. This ends up being passed to [`TextWriter.Write(char[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.write?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_TextWriter_Write_System_Char___), which writes it out as a string.

See [referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,196).

The documentation hints at this if you go digging far enough.

[`Console.WriteLine(char[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Char___):

> Writes the specified array of Unicode characters, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream.

[`TextWriter.Write(char[], int, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.write?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_TextWriter_Write_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_):

> This method will write `count` characters of data into this `TextWriter` from the buffer character array starting at position `index`.
>
> This overload is equivalent to the `Write(Char[])` overload for each character in `buffer` between `index` and (`index + count`).

You can see that there's nothing special about a `char[]` per se by writing:

```
Console.WriteLine((object)char_array);
```

This calls the `Console.WriteLine(object)` overload, which prints `System.Char[]`.